# 404 on every page, fresh install

Tags: magento2, apache, apache2, centos, php-5.6

I'll start off with saying that I am new to Magento. After installing Magento I only receive 404's. There is no styling either. I can't access the admin panel or anything, I just see "`whoops, our bad...`". I have been looking around for answers but nothing has worked.

So far I have tried:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Changing a few things in my `.htaccess (RewriteBase)`

I'm not sure what could be the issue now. Any help would be greatly appreciated! If any other information I will edit it in.

Extra info:

- Host: Webfaction
- Server: Apache 2.4.6
- Php: 5.6.31
- OS: CentOS (7 I believe)

Thank you  in advance!

update: I am unable to leave comments because you need 50 rep to leave a comment? Sadly I am unable to recompile due to our allotted memory through the host. Is it possible that uninstalling and reinstalling magento could solve the issue?

update 2: I was able to do both solutions and neither worked sadly.

Comment: Which folder are you in? And what modifications made inside `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the replies and the help! But it turned out to be a pretty simple fix that I just didn't realize. I was installing to the base url example.com/magento2/ but there was no magento2 folder. So it was 404'ing. I then just uninstalled and did the base url as example.com and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Magento application was switched to production mode, that's why static files are not accessible.

There are two solutions:

1. Deploy static files: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
2. Switch to developer mode: `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

As for 404 for admin panel - make sure you are using correct admin path (can be found in **app/etc/env.php**)

Also give full permission to your root magento directory.

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/MAGENTO_2_ROOT_DIRECTORY/
```

Comment: That's wrong , never ever give 777 to magento root directory it will open all the backdoors for attacks

Answer (score 0):

This may cause two things

1) check mod_write enabled in your server. if not enable also check allowoverride is all in apache server.

2) You can remove the folders from the directory with:

```
rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/pagecache var/di
```

and then re-compile again

```
 bin/magento setup:di:compile
 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Hope it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

you try this all command i hope your problem solve it and no any change so you remove your var folder after try this command.

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/MAGENTO_2_ROOT_DIRECTORY set permission/
php bin/magento index:reindex

Comment: 777 permission is not suggested in any case.